# plot orientation of points in scatter

Tags: python, vector, scatter

I have a scatter plot of points in [x,y]. I would like to plot also their orientation: each point represent a non spherical particle and I have its orientation in degree (-180,180) such that, for each data point, I have the following vector= [x,y,orientation].

Is there a way with matplotlib to plot in a 2D plot a small vector or, better, replace the pint with a small line with that orientation in space?

Comment: Have you taken a look at matplotlib's [quiver function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html)? It's able to render directed arrows at (x, y) points.

Comment: Perfect!! I did not know that function. Thank you!